# (Rails), How do I change "Home" link in my navigation menu to a logo-image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I just completed mimicking app creation just like I did in online lessons. I figure, I'd take a little step further by making my app look nicer.
**I am trying to change my "home" link text to an image.**
Surely, I have done that in HTML before but not in Rails. I am a bit confused because of "link_to" method. How do I do it, giving my current set-up?

*application.html.erb*

```
<header>
      <div class="header-logo">
        <%= link_to("Home", "/") %>
      </div>
           ...
```

*where routes.rb are*

```
get "/" => "home#top"
```

*home.scss*

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: 100%/1.5 'Avenir Next', 'Hiragino Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

ul, li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2d3133;
  font-size: 14px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline-width: 0;
}

form input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Common Layout ================================ */
body {
  color: #2d3133;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 1vh;
  background-image: url("/top.jpg");
}

.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 64px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f8fa;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  clear: both;
}

/* Header ================================ */
header {
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-logo {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 64px;
}

.header-logo a{
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.header-menus {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.header-menus li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 64px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.header-menus a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: black;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.header-menus .fa {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.header-menus input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 0 20px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 64px;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
}

/* Top ================================ */
.top-main {
  padding: 200px 0 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("/top.jpg");
}

.top-message {
  position: relative;
}

.top-main h2 {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.3;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.top-main p {
  font-size: 24px;
}

/* About ================================ */
.about-main {
  padding: 180px 8% 0;
  color: black;
}

.about-main h2 {
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.about-main p {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.about-img {
  width: 25%;
}

/* Form ================================ */
.form {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px #c1ced7;
}

.form-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 60px 0 20px;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #bcc8d4;
}

.form-body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.form-error {
  color: #ff4d75;
}

.form input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #57575f;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 110px;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.form input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  float: right;
}

.form-body:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Flash ================================ */
.flash {
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: black;
  background: rgb(251, 170, 88);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 64px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it `<%= link_to image_tag('image_here'), '/' %>`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
<%= link_to "#{image_tag("name-of-img-here.png")}".html_safe, root_path %>
```

Make sure you image is in the `app/assets/images/` folder for this to link correctly.

You will also likely need to add a class and then style it the image for it to look good.